# Theming rss in drupal 9

Tags: drupal, themes, rss

I have a mystery about RSS feed generated by Views RSS
In a Drupal 9 project I have a custom theme. In this custom theme I have
web/themes/custom/CUSTOM_theme/templates/views-view-row-rss.html.twig
but it never uses by Drupal.
In CUSTOM_theme.theme I have

```
function CUSTOM_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($theme_registry['views_view_row_rss']);
echo '</pre>';

}
```

and the path for the theme is good..
["path"]=>
string(34) "themes/custom/CUSTOM_theme/templates"

BUT in web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Theme/ThemeManager.php I add (only for test, of course, I don't want to modify this file) for the hook views-view-row-rss

```
      echo  '<pre>';
      var_dump($info);
```

And the result says the path is

["path"]=>
string(35) "modules/contrib/views_rss/templates"

More mysterious, in both cases, the thme_path is good
["theme path"]=>
string(24) "themes/custom/CUSTOM_theme"...

Do you know how to correct this and use the web/themes/custom/CUSTOM_theme/templates/views-view-row-rss.html.twig

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, someone found the trouble on a Discord, thanks to him.

```
/
 * Implemenents hook_theme_registry_alter().
 */
function views_rss_theme_registry_alter(array &$registry) {
  // Use the twig file that comes with this module so that the CDATA wrapper can
  // be added.
  $module_dir = \Drupal::service('extension.list.module')->getPath('views_rss');
  $registry['views_view_row_rss']['path'] = $module_dir . '/templates';
}
```

the module will search the path on views_rss each time.
So, the solution is to do

```
function CUSTOM_theme_registry_alter(array &$registry) {
  // Use the twig file that comes with this module so that the CDATA wrapper can
  // be added.
  $module_dir = \Drupal::service('extension.list.theme')->getPath('NAME OF THEME');
  $registry['views_view_row_rss']['path'] = $module_dir . '/templates';
}
```